# Calling a method from another file to a method in main

Tags: python

I have this main method trying to call delivering_packages from DeliveryManager:

```
from DeliveryManager import DeliveryManager

delivery_manager = DeliveryManager()

def deliver_all_packages(trucks):
    for i, truck in enumerate(trucks[:-1]):
        delivery_manager.delivering_packages(truck)  # Using the delivery instance here

    last_truck = trucks[-1]
    last_truck.depart_time = min(truck.time for truck in trucks[:-1])
    delivery_manager.delivering_packages(last_truck)  # Using the delivery instance here as well

trucks = [truck1, truck2, truck3]
deliver_all_packages(trucks)
```

Then in the other file of DeliveryManager:

```
class DeliveryManager:
    def __init__(self, truck):
        self.truck = truck

    def __str__(self):
        # Represent the package details as a string for easy printing and debugging
        return self.truck

    def delivering_packages(self, truck):
        not_delivered = [hash_table_package.lookup(packageID) for packageID in truck.packages]
        truck.packages.clear()
        current_address = extract_address(truck.address)

        while not_delivered:
            next_package = min(not_delivered, key=lambda package: distance_in_between(current_address, extract_address(package.address)))
            next_distance = distance_in_between(current_address, extract_address(next_package.address))
            truck.packages.append(next_package.ID)
            not_delivered.remove(next_package)
            truck.mileage += next_distance
            truck.address = next_package.address
            truck.time += datetime.timedelta(hours=next_distance / 18)
            next_package.delivery_time = truck.time
            next_package.departure_time = truck.depart_time
            current_address = extract_address(next_package.address)
```

I can't seem to reference delivering_packages properly. I think I need to rewrite the DeliveryManager file. Any fix or suggestions?

I'm trying to get delivering_packages to pass to a function in main properly. But I get an error that missing 1 required positional argument. Maybe I'm not initializing properly? I searched around and it's not working.

Comment: The `DeliveryManager()` class expects a truck to be passed when you create the instance. It's not clear what that's for, since `delivering_packages()` never uses `self.truck`, it gets another truck as a parameter.

Comment: It's very unclear what this class is supposed to do.

Comment: delivering_packages was originally in the main file, im just trying to move it to another file called DeliveryManager. So deliver_all_packages is in the main file try to reference delivering_packages from DeliveryManager. I could get rid of all the __init__ and __str__ parts but then the import doesn't work for some reason since it needs to be "initialized". I don't necessarily need DeliveryManager(), I just need delivering_packages().

Comment: It's still unclear why it needs to be a class. You can just define an ordinary function in the `DeliveryManager` module.

Comment: Yea it doesn't need to be a class. so in DeliveryManager I can just put:
def delivering_packages: .... ?
nothing else on top?
how do i go about importing it in main then?

Comment: `from DeliveryManager import delivering_packages`

Comment: Ok that kind of worked Barmar. But now I have an issue of circular import:
ImportError: cannot import name 'delivering_packages' from partially initialized module 'DeliveryManager' (most likely due to a circular import)

I think it's cause I'm importing from main now in DeliveryManager:
from main import hash_table_package, extract_address, distance_in_between

Comment: A module should be independent, it shouldn't import the file that imports it.

Comment: It seems like you're splitting this up for no good reason. If `DeliveryManager` only works with the functions that are defined in `main`, they should be a single script.